# How to convert following values to json(String to JSON Array)

Tags: json, string, grails, groovy

I have following data as String and I want them as a json.

```
data= [[[name: abc, age: 20], [name:xyz, age 25]], [[count: 2]]]
```

I tried Json.parse() and new JsonArray() but it threw an exception saying `"expection a ',' or ']'"`.
Can anyone help how can I convert it into JSON?

Comment: Cause this is not valid json

Comment: The JSON version of that is `[[{"name": "abc", "age": 20}, {"name": "xyz", "age": 25}], [{"count": 2 }]]` --- So, **parse that custom formatted string yourself**, using whatever technique you want, then create the JSON using some JSON library.

Comment: This string seems like it came from the `toString()` method of a list of lists of maps. Perhaps you would be better to go through the objects from which this string was created rather than through the string that was produced.

Comment: You don't have colon after age in "age 25". But it works as @tim_yates wrote, when colon is fixed in your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need

```
def json = JsonOutput.toJson(data)
```